# Create mask from QImage using non-transparent pixels

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, mask, alpha

I'm trying to create a monochrome [QBitmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbitmap.html) from a QImage. Pixels with an alpha greater than 0 should get turned on in the bitmap. It seems that this should be possible without explicitly looping through all the pixels.

I've gotten close by doing `QBitmap.fromImage(QImage(imagePath).createAlphaMask()`. However, only the pixels with an alpha of 1 get turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `QImage`, I used a `QPixmap`. This allowed me to call the function `mask`, which provided me with the `QBitMap` I desired:

```
QPixmap(imagePath).mask()
```